# Data storing design prob. Should I combine database + XML?

Tags: django, python-3.x, database-design, django-models

I'm running into a design problem.  Sorry if this isn't posted in the right categories, I'm really wondering where to put this question :-/

I did this small Zumba class application for a friend(referred as "the admin" from this point on).  It's a local web app made with django and sqlite to store the data. At first, there were only 2 categories of classes offered:  Regular and Advanced, and as such that part was hard coded to simplify the logic.

Now, I'm working on making this dynamic and allowing to create as many class type as it wants without me having to modify the code and database schema each time.
Example, there could be:
"Juniors" for 14 and less
"Regular" 
"Advanced"

The admin can then create "punchcards" for those respective classes.
Example: 
Regular 20 : includes 20 passes to any regular class.
Gold 30:  30 passes for any Gold class.
etc
In the app logic, a Regular pass holder cannot use it to access a Gold class since the price of that class is different.  So he must pass a Gold punchcard to access those classes.

Now, this is where I'm stuck.  How to add this information to a member account and be able to work with it?  My problem is that each time a punchcard is used, the number of passes left on it must decrease by one. And when a member buy a new card, it must allow to add the new passes to the amount remaining.
It can looks easy enough, simply add a field to the member model holding the number of passes left for each class type.(that's what Iw as doing before)  BUT, since I now want to let the admin create new type of classes, I'll never know how many of those fields will be required.(as the model would require one field per class type)

Then I thought to use a field holding a dict, [classtype_id, #_passes]  The classtype id would tell me if it's gold, regular, or any other class, and the number after would be the remaining passes.  But I searched and it seems you can't store a dict in a database(sadly).

Should I store this info into an XML file instead?  Would it slow down things much when combining database queries with file operations?

Any other solution to explore?

Here are the models if it can help:

```
class ClassType(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
default = models.BooleanField(default=False)




class MyUsers(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, db_index=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    member_since = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        self.member_since = datetime.date.today()
    self.fullname = self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
    super(MyUsers, self).save()


class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Class Name', max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Start Date & Time', blank=False, null=False)
    classtype = models.ForeignKey(ClassType, blank=False, null=False, default=1)
    status = models.IntegerField('Status', default=1)  # 1 = open, 0 = closed
    myusers = models.ManyToManyField(MyUsers, blank=True)



class Punchcard(models.Model):
    classes = models.IntegerField('Number of classes', blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, blank=False, null=False)
    label = models.CharField('Name of the punchcard', max_length=64, db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    classtype = models.ForeignKey(ClassType, blank=False, null=False)
    myusers = models.ManyToManyField(MyUsers, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Punchcard'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Punchcards'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the punchcard type from the punchcard

`PunchcardType` is connected to the class type and has information about the recharge number of classes, and the price

`Punchcard` should have a fk to a user and a fk to `PunchcardType`. They should hold the number of classes currently available to the user for that type. Every time the user attends a class you lower the appropriate token count by 1 and every time the user buys a punchcard you increase it by `cardType.classes` .

models.py should be like this:

```
class ClassType(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class MyUsers(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, db_index=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    member_since = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        self.member_since = datetime.date.today()
    self.fullname = self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
    super(MyUsers, self).save()


class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Class Name', max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Start Date & Time', blank=False, null=False)
    classtype = models.ForeignKey(ClassType, blank=False, null=False, default=1)
    status = models.IntegerField('Status', default=1)  # 1 = open, 0 = closed
    myusers = models.ManyToManyField(MyUsers, blank=True)


class PunchcardType(models.Model):
    classes = models.IntegerField('Number of classes', blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, blank=False, null=False)
    label = models.CharField('Name of the punchcard', max_length=64, db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    classtype = models.ForeignKey(ClassType, blank=False, null=False)


class Punchcard(models.Model):
    classes = models.IntegerField('Number of classes', blank=False, null=False)
    cardtype = models.ForeignKey(PunchcardType, blank=False, null=False)
    myuser = models.ForeignKey(MyUsers, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes alot of sense.  It never would have crossed my mind to separate it further.